# Do you now? - Ironic question

Tags: phrase-usage

Is this question only possible in this format or may it be phrased in other forms? For instance, if the previous sentence was something like 'You'd wish you could tire me out', could the ironic remark be 'Would I now?' meaning ('Of course, I can tire you out').

Comment: Yes, "Would I now?" and other variations are fine. Why wouldn't they be? (Though I wouldn't necessarily interpret your specific example to mean what you said it means.)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have to rethink the example, but the main thing was about the general usage of the expression, so your answer helps a lot! ;)